# Using selenium with grid servers parallel visiting multiple URLs and sharing the same cookies

Tags: python, firefox, selenium

If you don't want waste your time to look at the details, please go to the **Here is the problem** part. If you are very impatient, please directly go to the last part of this question.

First of all, I'm not using the selenium to do automatic testing, I'm using it to scraping (collecting data) from specific websites. The reason to using selenium is a long story, I'm not going to talk about it in here.

This is the environment:

```
Client side:
    Python 2.7
    selenium 2.43.0

Server side:
    CentOS
    selenium 2.43.1 (both the hub and grids)
    Firefox 32
    1 selenium hub and multiple selenium grids (running on different servers)
```

Currently we have workable scrapers (or data collectors, if you prefer) based on this, but they are scraping pages in serial, and now we decide to using multithreading to speed it up.

But the selenium [FAQ](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions) said:

> WebDriver is not thread-safe.

So we are going to have multiple WebDriver (firefox) instance in a scraper, and visiting different URLs.

**Here is the problem**:

We need the scrapers sharing cookies (and cache if possible) between WebDrivers that scraping a same website via a same proxy. But we not don't want the scrapers sharing cookies with another scrapers that scraping different websites or via different proxies.

I've did some research on this.

I know the client can specify a profile path for the selenium firefox webdriver(which are running on the grid server). But the selenium not able to create and delete the profile automatically, we have to do it on our own, this means we might need to create the profile dynamically, and delete it if it's no longer needed, because we don't know how many scrapers/websites/proxies will be use - this sounds not a good idea.

The second choice is sync the cookies in the code, but the selenium prevent to access cookies that doesn't belonging to the current domain, this might become tricky when the web site has two or more domains. Also, I can patch 2 JS files in the webdriver.xpi file to remove this limit (See [here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=1953)), but this requires me to patch the grid server - sounds a bad idea too.

So, is there any possibility to make the selenium remote webdrivers (Firefox instances) sharing cookies, and doesn't require to modify the selenium or have a "babysitter" program to care of the selenium server?

Thanks.

Comment: why not use multiprocessing instead of multithreading? that way each instance will have its own webdrive, if you want to share the webdriver between threads, maybe make it a Singelton..

Comment: @Urb I'm afraid that use multiprocessing still having the same problem - unable to share cookies between 2 processes (instead of threads). If a website is not open for register, and we have only one account for the website, then we have to scrape this website use single process (or thread), this is so bad.

Comment: ok, then what about [add_cookie](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.add_cookie)

Comment: @Urb add_cookie function is not able to add cookies that doesn't match current domain. For example, if I want to add a cookie belongs to **google.com**, but the selenium current URL is **www.youtube.com**, then I'll get an exception, and can't add that cookie. But in fact, **www.youtube.com** surely referenced some JavaScripts which belong to **google.com**, so use add_cookie is not suit for this job.